# How to disable a shell without disabling minimize, maximize and close button in SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I'm trying to disable a shell in SWT using

```
sell.setEnabled(false);
```

this is working fine, I want to prevent user from doing actions, but in the same time I want to allow him to minimize the shell. The problem is that `setEnabled(false)` will disable the entire shell.

Have you please an idea about that?

Comment: Possibly interesting: [SWT - Grey out and disable current shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679450/swt-grey-out-and-disable-current-shell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to disable the content of the shell. Then why don't you just add a container (Composite) as the main content in the shell and disable/enable it as desired?. That won't affect the shell and, therefore, the minimize button will keep working.

```
final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
final Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
composite.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: There is no need for an extra container. Disabling all contained controls works equally well and saves an extra widget (see my answer).

Comment: Adding an extra container allows to disable all the content in a single instruction, without a loop.

Comment: Rüdiger : I can not mark the two answers so don't blame me for that ;)

Comment: @Alberto I don't see what's wrong with a for loop, a Composite without a reason however is a waste of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling the Shell itself, disable the controls that it contains. Something like this:

```
Control[] children = shell.getChildren();
for( Control control : children ) {
  control.setEnabled( false );
}
```